# Magento 1 modify product attribute related to stock update

Tags: magento, attributes, product, stock

The issue concerns a Magento ver. 1.14.0.1 installation with some marketplace (mirakl) and feeds (datafeedmanager) features.

**Situation**
I have to add a product attribute named *marketplace_exclusive* that will be set to true if the product is sold by the sellers of the marketplace and **not** by the operator ( the hosting magento shop ).
**This attribute is relevant** when it comes to data feeds as some ERP will not accept products which would have an empty Operator Stock even though they'd have a valid Marketplace Stock.

**Where your help's needed**
I can't compute it by chance and need to figure out the best context to make sure the data is always relevant in catalog_product_flat table and product collections.

**Vagrant thoughts**

- I've thought about extending **catalog_product_flat index** without being sure it was the best or only place to handle it.
- I've tried also to focus on stock_item status update but pinning down the precise spot is far from obvious to me.
- I've considered listening to quote events to update the attribute once an order is confirmed/placed but again this feels foggy.
- I've dismissed [the cron lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294678/magento-auto-change-inventory-stock-availability-on-quantity-update) ( though I haven't considered this specific solution ) because I'm concerned about my client's demands of perfs and data being always on point.
- And last but not least **catalog_product_save_after** also left me puzzled.

I would assume the right answer to this question may be a mix of these leads but I'm having a hard time to draw the final stroke on this.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to your question is related to this:
When do you need to check this value?

- For catalog purposes: to generate a feed, to show/hide on the shop.
- For sales integration: to notify the ERP or some marketplace partner after a sale.

If you use this for catalog purposes then it should be some cron o task that can get this value for the products you need to update.

If you need this for sales integration then you should add a column marketplace_exclusive to `sales_flat_order_item`. And add an observer that manage this value after fire the event `sales_order_place_after`

Hope it helps,
Thanks

Comment: Thank you @César for your answer.
I need it for ERP/marketplace after a sale, however my exports are done through catalog, not sales, because of the datafeedmanager module ( which I highly not recommend ).
Also considering : stock could be changed through import files or daily admin actions. This would hint heavily in the cron direction - let's say, twice or three times a day?

Comment: Hello @NoireMunich
In my last company I developed a module from scracth for a marketplace integration (Zalando and eBay) and I finished doing everything on my own (sales integration and catalog feed) avoiding 3rd party modules like datafeedmanager.
I don't know how is your integration flow but I guess that you need this value only for sales integration, so this must be a sales_item attribute. 
It's a complex topic to treat here without having all the needed info.

Comment: Hello @César
I'm holding your answer as the way to go further in my task, I don't have a definitive answer yet and a colleague of mine is picking up the task ( onboarding for new member ).
I thought the product attribute would be appropriate but the job just takes ages so my colleague will have a look at the index option.
As a matter of fact we don't really need the value for the sales integration but more for the inventory management, so it seems really related to the catalog. 
Hopefully I'll be able to post a full debrief once task is over.